# Allow only fixed text in an XML element via XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am currently working on an XSD file, and I am trying to create a doc-copyright element that must have this text between the start tag and end tag:

```
"This feed and its format is copyright RET 2016"
```

And the element must be an empty element.

I did try looking at W3C Schools for examples, but I didn't find what I was looking for.

So far I have...

```
<xs:element name="doc-copyright" value="This feed and its format is
copyright RET 2016"/>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If it has text between the start and end tag then it is not empty, by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can used `@fixed`,

```
<xs:element name="doc-copyright"
            fixed="This feed and its format is copyright RET 2016"/>
```

to allow ***either***

```
<doc-copyright>This feed and its format is copyright RET 2016</doc-copyright>
```

***or***

```
<doc-copyright/>
```

but to request *an element that must have specific text between the start and end tag **and** must be an empty element* makes no sense.

---

**Update:**

In order to disallow the empty case (`<doc-copyright/>`), you might think that you could add a restriction,

```
  <xs:element name="doc-copyright"
              fixed="This feed and its format is copyright RET 2016">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:minLength value="1"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

However, this doesn't work because the value of `@fixed` is taken as the default when `doc-copyright` is empty, and this default value meets the `minLength/@value="1"` restriction.

Instead, you can back-off `@fixed` and simply make your required text be the only possible enumeration:

```
  <xs:element name="doc-copyright">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="This feed and its format is copyright RET 2016"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks! My instructor just told us that he made a typo. Doc-copyright shouldn't be an empty element.